# Unable to click 'about-button' section with Selenium, browser shuts down immediately. How to fix it?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

So, I am currently working with silenium and for some reason some funcitons doesn't work. When I open the my website with silenium, it works fine. But when I want to add functionality to it like clicking on a button, after launching the code the browser imidiatelly shuts down. The problem is with the `about-button` section.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\webdriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:5500/pages/index.html")
about_button = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "about-link")
about_button.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

Chat GPT told me that one of the problem why it doesn't work could be my extentions, I turned them off. I also tried replacing `about_button` with `about_button.click()`, still doesn't work.

I am expecting the program to open my website that I am hosting via LiveServer and redirect it to the about subpage.

There is also this error on the 11th line:

```
Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"about-link"}
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.127)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B28893+48451]
    (No symbol) [0x00ABB8A1]
    (No symbol) [0x009C5058]
    (No symbol) [0x009F0467]
    (No symbol) [0x009F069B]
    (No symbol) [0x00A1DD92]
    (No symbol) [0x00A0A304]
    (No symbol) [0x00A1C482]
    (No symbol) [0x00A0A0B6]
    (No symbol) [0x009E7E08]
    (No symbol) [0x009E8F2D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D88E3A+2540266]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00DC8959+2801161]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00DC295C+2776588]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00BB2280+612144]
    (No symbol) [0x00AC4F6C]
    (No symbol) [0x00AC11D8]
    (No symbol) [0x00AC12BB]
    (No symbol) [0x00AB4857]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76C07D59+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x778CB74B+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x778CB6CF+191]
  File "C:\Users\Vojte\OneDrive\Desktop\Grind\SKILLS\Coding\testing-bwt\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    about_button = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "about-link")
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"about-link"}
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.127)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B28893+48451]
    (No symbol) [0x00ABB8A1]
    (No symbol) [0x009C5058]
    (No symbol) [0x009F0467]
    (No symbol) [0x009F069B]
    (No symbol) [0x00A1DD92]
    (No symbol) [0x00A0A304]
    (No symbol) [0x00A1C482]
    (No symbol) [0x00A0A0B6]
    (No symbol) [0x009E7E08]
    (No symbol) [0x009E8F2D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D88E3A+2540266]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00DC8959+2801161]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00DC295C+2776588]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00BB2280+612144]
    (No symbol) [0x00AC4F6C]
    (No symbol) [0x00AC11D8]
    (No symbol) [0x00AC12BB]
    (No symbol) [0x00AB4857]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76C07D59+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x778CB74B+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x778CB6CF+191]
```

PS
If I write like an id*ot, I'm sorry, this is my first post.

Comment: I would try and debug whether or not the about_button is a real element. Maybe you didn't manage to "catch" it with find_element and then when you are running rest of the code it fails. Also it might be that you are looking for this element to early (you are targeting this right but the browser does not yet created it and you are getting nothing for your find_element)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a relevant amount of HTML, including enough ancestor elements to get an idea about the page structure.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
about_button = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "about-link")
about_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry for wasting your time, the problem was on my side in my html code, I didn't give id element prefix to the About line. One more time, sorry for wasting your time